# Statsmodels Error with R ntoation

Tags: r, python-3.x, statsmodels

want to use R notation for my regression and am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
d = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3), columns = ['a'], index = np.arange(3))
d['b'] = np.arange(3)+2
smf.OLS('a ~ b', data=d).fit()
```

However, I then get a long error message, involving ValueError: unrecognized data structures:  / .

What is happening here? Many thanks!

Comment: `smf.ols(formula="a ~ b", data=d).fit()`

Comment: ah, it does work now.  apparently OLS instead of ols yields this very strange error. many thanks!